# Design approach for building static framework and internal linking with other open source libraries

Tags: ios, networking, frameworks, static-libraries, afnetworking

I'm creating a static Framework to distribute to other projects. I have some confusion with the design approach for building the framework. I have never built a framework before.

I'm building something similar to [AdColony framework](https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK) where I'll pass some unique id to framework and it will internally call several APIs and it will transfer final output back to the application with proper delegates. And in that AdColony framework only one .h file is public.

I'm wondering some questions:

1) I'm planning to use AFNetworking for all server communication and parsing. So while building framework how I can link my static framework with AFNetworking. AFNetworking headers will be visible in final .framework output ? If external AFNetworking linking is required to my framework so is it a good approach that I'm forcing other developers to include AFNetworking ? Or i have to write down my own basic networking layer ?

2) Can I hide my all wrapper and Model classes and just make 1 class visible to developers for configuration and handling output ?

Apart from above questions if you have some best design approach for building this framework then please do suggest.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you planning to distribute the framework or is it for personal(or internal) use only?

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu Yes I am planning to distribute the framework. Do you have personal opinion or suggestion on above question ?

Comment: I was going to suggest that you create your own private Cocoapods library, given that you don't want to hide the implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **1. You can do two things:**

- Add AFNetworking to your framework. And set the header of the AFNetworking like public headers. You could change some include to create a clean include headers.
- Link your framework with AFNetworking, and force other developer to link AFNetworking.

**How to know which approach to follow?**

I would use the first approach if my framework will provide some Network Layer. And I will maintain my project. The second approach is useful if you only use AFNetworking for your internal implementation. But you will need maintain your framework when AFNetworking change something that you are using.

---

### 2 . Yes, you can.

You can set public headers. So, if you want to have only one public class you need to set that  header as public. Remember that all the method in the .h are public. So if you want to ensure that no one can call your method, you need to put the method declaration in a category that you will use in your .m

Another suggestion: take a look to this [project](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework).

Comment: " You can have only one header public." Excuse me? How in the earth did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @KamilKocemba: Maybe explain to me wrong. I mean that he can set one header like public. Because one of his question was: "just make 1 class visible to developers for configuration and handling output ?" So my answer is: "yes, you can have or set one header as public". Sorry for my english. :)

Comment: @dcorbatta Looks like Kamil has down-voted you and he doesn't understand the actual question. I looked on his solution too. He has posted something related to cocoapods. I don't understand how cocoapods is responsible for building static framwework and internal linking. Just FYI: I am gonna use your second approach where I would be using internal implementation of AFNetworking as I am not providing any networking layer to other developers

Comment: Mmm, cocoapods is for distribute your framework and for resolve amy dependence necessary for your framework.

Comment: It is a pity that @KamilKocemba has downvote my answer only because he didn't understand the question.